# Prove that $Im(A)+Ker(A)=R^n \iff Ker(A^2)=Ker(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}\def\Ker{\operatorname{Ker}}$How to prove that for any squared matrix such that $ \Im(A)+\Ker(A)=\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $\Ker(A^2)=\Ker(A)$.
It is evident to me that it is true if $A$ is zero matrix or $A$ is nonsingular.
How to prove if $A$ singular nonzero matrix?

Thank you!

Comment: Suppose ${\rm im}(A) + \ker(A) = \mathbb R^n$. What can you say about ${\rm im}(A) \cap \ker(A)$?  Similarly, suppose that $\ker(A^2) = \ker(A)$. What does this tell you about the action of $A$ on ${\rm im}(A)$?

Comment: Have a look at this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846178/show-ker-alpha-ker-alpha2-iff-ker-alpha-and-im-alpha-are-disjoi

Answer (score 5):

The dimensions of $Im(A)$ and $Ker(A)$ always sum to $n$, so the condition that $\operatorname{Im}(A) + \operatorname{Ker} (A) = {\mathbb R}^n$ implies that each $x \in {\mathbb R}^n$ can be written  in the form $Ay + z$ for some $z \in \operatorname{Ker}(A)$. If this holds then $Ax = A^2y$. Thus $\operatorname{Im}(A) = \operatorname{Im}(A^2)$. In particular they have the same dimension, so being of complementary dimension $\operatorname{Ker}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(A^2)$ have the same dimension. So since $\operatorname{Ker}(A) \subset \operatorname{Ker}(A^2)$ they must be the same.

Conversely, if $\operatorname{Ker}(A) + \operatorname{Im}(A) \neq \mathbb R^n$, then since their dimensions add to $n$ there must be some nonzero $x \in \operatorname{Ker}(A) \cap \operatorname{Im}(A)$. So $x = Ay$ with $Ax = A^2y = 0$. Hence $y \in ker(A^2)$ but $y \notin \operatorname{Ker}(A)$. We conclude that $\operatorname{Ker}(A) \neq \operatorname{Ker}(A^2)$.

Comment: Why $ Ker(A) \subset Ker(A^2) $?

Comment: Because if $Ax = 0$ then $A^2x = A(Ax) = A(0) = 0$.